# A2Hosting shared host plan for emails with DNS and website hosted on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, email, server, dns, cpanel

I have my DNS service provided by AWS Route 53 and my website runs on an AWS Lightsail instance.
The DNS has an `A` record pointing to the Lightsail instance.

In order to have an unlimited amount of custom domain mailboxes, I want to buy a CPanel shared hosting from A2Hosting and let its mail server handle everything.

I am confused about what I have to do to set up this scenario.

Do I have to set the `mydomain.com` `MX` record to point to my A2Hosting shared hosting? A2Hosting tells me that my `POP` and `SMTP` servers are both `mail.mydomain.com`, but how could it knows?

Should I set my AWS `MX` record to point `mail.mydomain.com` and add in AWS an `A` record mapping `mail.mydomain.com` to the actual IP address of the shared hosting machine?

Should I get a dedicated IP for the A2 shared hosting or is there any other way?

Will CPanel and its mail server "connect" to the flow seamlessly or will I have to do anything else to receive and send trusted emails *(all the DMARK and DKIM stuff)*?

Thanks so much to anyone willing to give me help on the matter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Should I set my AWS MX record to point mail.mydomain.com and add in AWS an A record mapping mail.mydomain.com to the actual IP address of the shared hosting machine?

That is exactly what you want to do in order to start receiving emails at the cPanel server.

> Should I get a dedicated IP for the A2 shared hosting or is there any other way?

There is no need for this. However, it would not hurt to do this. You'll find that sending messages from an IP address that is shared with other customers will sometimes cause your messages to go to spam due to abuse fro m other users on the server. Good hosting providers can help to mitigate this problem, but I wouldn't count on it if my business needed top reliability at all times.

> Will CPanel and its mail server "connect" to the flow seamlessly

Typically the cPanel server its self already has the "MX routing" set to local which means that cPanel will accept messages when they arrive for your domain. However, it is possible that this could get set to "remote" in which case emails would arrive to the cPanel server, and then be rejected. If you find that the MX and corresponding A record are set properly but you're unable to receive email, check the "MX Routing" icon in your cPanel account.

> will I have to do anything else to receive and send trusted emails (all the DMARK and DKIM stuff)?

You'll also of course need to setup email accounts. And then it wouldn't hurt to get familar with your spam mitigation options. My personal favorite is BoxTrapper:

https://support.cpanel.net/hc/en-us/articles/360057060793-Can-cPanel-s-BoxTrapper-Help-Reduce-Spam-How-to-enable-BoxTrapper

As for sending messages, because you're not using your cPanel server for DNS, you'll need to manually copy over all of the email related DNS records from the cPanel dns zone, to your AWS hosted DNS server. This would include the SPF and DKIM records. Typically you won't find a DMARC record setup by default, but cPanel's Zone editor actually makes the process of generating a DMARC record very easy. You could generate the DMARC record on cPanel, and then just copy it over to the AWS server.

Of course, if you were using cPanel for your DNS, those records would be automatically managed and updated for you without the need for your intervention.

Comment: Thanks, that clarified all my doubts!

Comment: Glad to be able to help out!